# CustomView doesnt draw anything

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i have a customview to draw inside a toggle button, but when a inflate the layout i cant see anything..
I put a linearlayout as root view and inside i set my needed element.
This is my code:
The root class for instantiate the root view()

```
public abstract class ReplyView extends LinearLayout {

    public ReplyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ReplyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ReplyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        initializeComponents();
    }

    public abstract void initializeComponents();

    public abstract String getResult();
}
```

My custom implementation of this class:

```
public class YesNoReplyView extends ReplyView {

    private ToggleButton toggleButton;

    public YesNoReplyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public YesNoReplyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public YesNoReplyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeComponents() {
        toggleButton = new ToggleButton(getContext());
        toggleButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        toggleButton.setTextOn("Si");
        toggleButton.setTextOn("No");
        toggleButton.setBackground(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_toggle));        
    addView(toggleButton, new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }


    @Override
    public String getResult() {
        String result = toggleButton.isChecked() ? "Si" : "No";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Whats the problem? I see each element and all its visible..

Comment: what are you doing wuth baselayout? seems that it is not used anywhere...

Comment: Hi, i edited my code and removed baselayout(Was a simple relativelayout), before i was extending from view and now from LinearLayout for better performance.

Comment: seems you forgot about the orientation

Comment: i set orientation to horizontal but i cant see anything even though

Comment: tried running hierarchyviewer?